# Specify python-mode.el's python executable

Tags: python, emacs, ipython, anaconda

I recently installed anaconda, which installed its own python 2.7 into ~/anaconda2/bin/python. I wish for my IPy mode to point to the anaconda python so that I can use them together. However, IPy instead uses /usr/bin/python for its executable. This in spite of my using `customize-variable` to set `py-use-local-default` to `t` and `py-shell-local-path` to the anaconda python. What else might I consider to get my emacs IPy mode to play nicely with anaconda?

Here's every line in my .emacs file that even mentions python:

> `; (require 'python-settings)
>
> ; (require 'ein)
>
> (setq py-install-directory "~/.emacs.d/python-mode")
>
> (add-to-list 'load-path py-install-directory)
>
> (require 'python-mode)
>
> (setq python-shell-interpreter "~/anaconda2/bin/python"
>         python-shell-interpreter-args "-i console --matplotlib")
>
> (setq-default py-shell-name "ipython")
>
> (setq-default py-which-bufname "IPython")
>
> ; use the wx backend, for both mayavi and matplotlib
>   (setq py-python-command-args
>     '("--gui=wx" "--pylab=wx" "-colors" "Linux"))
>
> ;; responsible for the annoying window rearrangement behavior after every code execution? Nope.
>
> (setq py-force-py-shell-name-p t)
>
> ; switch to the interpreter after executing code
>
> (setq py-shell-switch-buffers-on-execute-p nil)
>
> (setq py-switch-buffers-on-execute-p nil)
>
> (setq py-shell-local-path "/home/ftamborello/anaconda2/bin/python"
>         py-use-local-default t)
>
> ; don't split windows
>
> (setq py-split-window-on-execute-p nil)
>
> ; try to automagically figure out indentation
>
> (setq py-smart-indentation t)
>
> ; enable flycheck syntax support
>
> ; (add-hook 'after-init-hook #'global-flycheck-mode)`

Comment: Seems worth a bug report: Either https://gitlab.com/python-mode-devs/python-mode/issues or https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode

Comment: Maybe you can add this to your `.emacs` ?
`(setq python-shell-interpreter "~/anaconda2/bin/python")

Comment: @ChakravarthyRaghunandan That seemed to have no effect: `^[[?12l^[[?25himport pandas as pd ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)    <ipython-input-2-af55e7023913> in <module>()    ----> 1 import pandas as pd    ImportError: No module named pandas`

Comment: Ah I see you are using `python-mode` instead of the stock `python.el` which comes built-in with emacs. My code only works for the inbuilt `python-mode` provided by emacs. My bad.

Comment: look into `elpy`, it's a python development environment for emacs, and it works well with anaconda in my experience. It's well documented too, and you can make sure it knows where to look for python if you don't want it to use /usr/bin/python (it probably will by default).  https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy